# Jack output does't work anymore on windows

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, headphone-jack

I have an ASUS K53SD with a dual boot Archlinux/Windows 7 x64. Everything worked fine with audio until last week when I realize that my Jack output doesn't work anymore on windows while it still works on linux...

I tried to reinstall realtek driver but the problem is still the same, when I plug the jack a popup say "Jack inserted", speakers are muted but I have no sound in my headphones.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look to the Windows *Sound* CPL. Most likely the *Headphones* device is misconfigured. Right-click on *Headphones* and ensure that it is *enabled* and that it is set as the *Default Device*.
[image]

Comment: Headphones does not appear in this section...

Comment: Notice the image above: be sure "Show Disabled Devices" and "Show Disconnected Devices" are checked.